# Javafx TableView not showing data

Tags: javafx, tableview

I used `ObservableList` to populate the `TableView` but the problem is that the data is not showing in the table I don't know what is the problem because the number of rows is exactly like I added them [capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fOb2o.jpg) but there is nothing in the cells!
here is the code of the controller:

```
public class EnlistDim {

    private static final String DEFAULT="-fx-text-background-color: black; -fx-background-color: steelblue;-fx-fill: red ;";
    @FXML
    private TableView<Parameter> tab;


    @FXML
    public void initialize() {
        final ObservableList<Parameter> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
        new Parameter("Query","Access method","Sequential scan"),
                new Parameter("Query","Access method","in memory"),
        new Parameter("Query","Operation","join"),
        new Parameter("Query","Operation","Scan"),
        new Parameter("Query","Operation","Sort"),
        new Parameter("Database","Buffer management","Without buffer"),
        new Parameter("Database","Buffer management","FIFO"),
        new Parameter("Database","Buffer management","LIFO"),
        new Parameter("Database","Buffer management","LRU"),
        new Parameter("Database","Buffer management","Other"),

        new Parameter("Database","Optimization structure","Not used"),
        new Parameter("Database","Optimization structure","Partionning"),
        new Parameter("Database","Optimization structure","Materialized View"),
        new Parameter("Database","Optimization structure","compresssion"),

        new Parameter("Database","System storage type","Database SQL"),
        new Parameter("Database","System storage type","New SQL"),
        new Parameter("Database","System storage type","Document"),
        new Parameter("Database","System storage type","Graph"),
        new Parameter("Database","System storage type","NVRAM"),
        new Parameter("Database","System storage type","key value store"),

        new Parameter("Database","Data storage type","Row Oriented"),
        new Parameter("Database","Data storage type","Column Oriented"),
        new Parameter("Database","Data storage type","Hybrid Oriented"),

        new Parameter("Hardware","Processing device","CPU"),
        new Parameter("Hardware","Processing device","GPU"),
        new Parameter("Hardware","Processing device","FPGA"),


        new Parameter("Hardware","Storage device","RAM"),
        new Parameter("Hardware","Storage device","SSD"),
        new Parameter("Hardware","Storage device","NVRAM"),


        new Parameter("Hardware","Communication device","Modem"),
        new Parameter("Hardware","Communication device","Cable"),
        new Parameter("Hardware","Communication device","FaxModem"),
        new Parameter("Hardware","Communication device","Router")

           );
        tab.setEditable(true);
        tab.setItems(data);



        tab.setStyle(DEFAULT);

    }

}
```

and the code of `Parameter` class:

```
class  Parameter {

   SimpleStringProperty cat;
   SimpleStringProperty subCat;
   SimpleStringProperty subSubCat;

        Parameter(String cat, String subCat, String subSubCat) {
        this.cat = new SimpleStringProperty(cat);
        this.subCat = new SimpleStringProperty(subCat);
        this.subSubCat = new SimpleStringProperty(subSubCat);
    }

    public String getCat() {
        return cat.get();
    }
    public void setCat(String c) {
        cat.set(c);
    }

    public String getSubCat() {
        return subCat.get();
    }
    public void setSubCat(String sc) {
        subCat.set(sc);
    }

    public String getSubSubCat() {
        return subSubCat.get();
    }
    public void setSubSubCat(String ssc) {
        subSubCat.set(ssc);
    }

}
```

Comment: Where do you set the `cellValueFactory`s?

Comment: Thank you for your response, i don't know what is it, should i add it to make the code works ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to actually tell the `TableView` HOW to display the data. This is done using a `CellValueFactory`. Basically, you need to tell each column of the table what type of data it holds and where it gets that data from.

You need to start by defining your columns (give them an `fx:id` either in the FXML file or in SceneBuilder):

```
@FXML
TableColumn<Parameter, String> colCategory;
@FXML
TableColumn<Parameter, String> colSubCategory;
@FXML
TableColumn<Parameter, String> colSubSubCategory;
```

Each `TableColumn` takes two Type parameters. The first defines the object being displayed (`Parameter`). The second is the data type for this column (all yours are `String`).

Once the columns are defined, you need to set their `CellValueFactory` in your `initialize()` method:

```
colCategory.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Parameter, String>("cat"));
colSubCategory.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Parameter, String>("subCat"));
colSubSubCategory.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Parameter, String>("subSubCat"));
```

Here you are telling each column where to find the data to be displayed. The last argument on the line, in the quotes, is the name of your property within the `Parameter` object.

So, when JavaFX populates your table, it will takes these steps to populate each column (`colCategory`, for example):

1. Get the `CellValueFactory` for `colCategory`.
2. The factory is a `PropertyValueFactory`, so determine which class holds the property (in this case it is the `Parameter` class)
3. Look in the `Parameter` class for a `String` property by the name of "cat"
4. Populate the column's cell with the value of the `cat` property.